# Attributed titleLabel in UIButton (IB) does not respect setFont

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2

when I set the title of a UIButton in IB as attributed and try to change the font programmatically:

```
button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
```

font does not increase/decrease...

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: One way would be to set NSFontAttributeName on titleLabel's  'attributedText' property

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with attributted string for the button title you have to set the font with `NSFontAttributeName` attribute when you are creating the attributted string.

Answer (score 0):

call setAttributedTitle:forState: of UIButton to set the attributed title

Comment: I am not looking to change the title... just the font. Basically want to button.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true but this doesn't work with attributed text